# React Native : Show a modal view from a tabbar button

Tags: javascript, react-native, modal-dialog, tabbar

I'm using React Native for my app. Everything is going well except one thing.

I would like to implement a modal view that is displayed when the user clicks on the middle button (+) of the tabbar. It looks like the Youtube app.

[image]

[image]

After serveral days, I didn't find an effective solution.

Here is my code for the the tabbar and the navigator.

**Tabbar :**

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer >
      <Tabs.Navigator tabBarOptions={{labelStyle: {fontSize:14}, activeTintColor: 'purple', showLabel: false}  } 
> 
        <Tabs.Screen name="Ventes" component={venteScreenNavigator} 
        options={{
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
              <View style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
                <Image
                  source={require("./assets/Buy.png")}
                  resizeMode="contain"
                  style={{
                    width: 25,
                    height: 25,
                    tintColor: focused ? "black" : "gray",
                  }}
                />
              </View>
            ),
          }}
          />
        <Tabs.Screen name="Map" component={mapScreenNavigator}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <View style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
              <Image
                source={require("./assets/geolocalisationicone.png")}
                resizeMode="contain"
                style={{
                  width: 25,
                  height: 25,
                  tintColor: focused ? "black" : "gray",
                }}
              />
            </View>
          )
        }}
        />
        
        <Tabs.Screen name="Liste" component={listeScreenNavigator}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <View style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
              <Image
                source={require("./assets/Document.png")}
                resizeMode="contain"
                style={{
                  width: 25,
                  height: 25,
                  tintColor: focused ? "black" : "gray",
                }}
              />
            </View>
          ),
        }}
        />
        <Tabs.Screen name="Espace" component={espaceScreenNavigator}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <View style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
              <Image
                source={require("./assets/monespaceicone.png")}
                resizeMode="contain"
                style={{
                  width: 25,
                  height: 25,
                  tintColor: focused ? "black" : "gray",
                }}
              />
            </View>
          ),
        }}
        />
        
      </Tabs.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    
  )
}
```

**Nav :**

```
const venteScreenNavigator = () => {
    return (

        <stack.Navigator>
            <stack.Screen name="Ventes" component={Ventes} 
            options={{
                headerRight: ()=> (
                    
                   <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginRight: 10}}>
                        <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Image
                        style={styles.image}
                        source={require('../assets/Plus.png')}>
                        </Image>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Image
                        style={styles.image}
                        source={require('../assets/Chat.png')}>
                        </Image>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                   </View>        
                )                
            }}
            />
            <stack.Screen name="Screens" component={Screens}
            />
        </stack.Navigator>
    )
}

export {venteScreenNavigator}





const mapScreenNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <stack.Navigator>
            
            <stack.Screen name="Map" component={Map}
            options={{
                headerRight: ()=> (
                    
                   <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginRight: 10}}>
                        <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Image
                        style={styles.image}
                        source={require('../assets/Plus.png')}>
                        </Image>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Image
                        style={styles.image}
                        source={require('../assets/Chat.png')}>
                        </Image>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                   </View>                 
                )               
            }}
            />
            <stack.Screen name="Screens" component={Screens}
            />
        </stack.Navigator>
    )
}

export {mapScreenNavigator}

const listeScreenNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <stack.Navigator>
            <stack.Screen name="Liste" component={Liste}
            options={{
                headerRight: ()=> (
                    
                   <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginRight: 10}}>
                        <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Image
                        style={styles.image}
                        source={require('../assets/Plus.png')}>
                        </Image>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Image
                        style={styles.image}
                        source={require('../assets/Chat.png')}>
                        </Image>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                   </View>
                    
                    
                )
                
            }}
            />
            <stack.Screen name="Screens" component={Screens}
            />
        </stack.Navigator>
    )
}

export {listeScreenNavigator}

const espaceScreenNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <stack.Navigator>
            <stack.Screen name="Espace" component={Espace}
            options={{
                headerRight: ()=> (
                    
                   <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginRight: 10}}>
                        <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Image
                        style={styles.image}
                        source={require('../assets/Plus.png')}>
                        </Image>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Image
                        style={styles.image}
                        source={require('../assets/Chat.png')}>
                        </Image>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                   </View>
                )
                
            }}
            />
            <stack.Screen name="Screens" component={Screens}
            />
            <stack.Screen name="Profil" component={Profil}
            options={{
                headerRight: ()=> (
                    
                   <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginRight: 10}}>
                        <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Image
                        style={styles.image}
                        source={require('../assets/Setting.png')}>
                        </Image>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                   </View>                    
                )               
            }}
            />
            <stack.Screen name="ModifierProfil" component={ModifierProfil}
            />           
        </stack.Navigator>
      
    )
}

export {espaceScreenNavigator}
```

Can you please tell me how to do displayed the modal when the user clicks on the tabbar button ?

Thanks guys !

Comment: Create Custom UI for Tab Bar, react-navigation provides one prop using which you can create custom UI for Tab Bar. So you'll be create custom UI and on click of '+' icon you can open modal. I would suggest you to use 'react-native-modal'.

 `<Tab.Navigator tabBar={props => <MyCustomTabBar {...props} />}> `

In this `MyCustomTabBar` you can code your custom tab bar, And can code Modal inside that you need.

Comment: I think you're looking for a bottom sheet here: https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try this code**
   
 const PopUpTask = ({navigation}) => {
        React.useEffect(() => {
          const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('tabPress', e => {
            // Prevent default behavior
            e.preventDefault();
    // Here you create it
            alert('Default behavior prevented');
            // Do something manually
            // ...
          });
    
          return unsubscribe;
        }, [navigation]);
    
        return (
          <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Text>Home!</Text>
          </View>
        );
      };
```