# How to make tabBar screen like modal in React native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabbar

[image]

I have 4 tab Bars.

Let's say each tab name is A, B, C, D.

If I stayed on tab screen C and click tab D,

I want to make transparent background of D which shows previous screen, C on behind.

Even though I make backgroundColor `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)` on tab Screen D, I guess tab screen is not stacked like stack navigation, it just shows gray color like above.

Can I make transparent background showing previous screen by `tabBar navigator`?

Comment: Why not use a modal and make the modal transparent?

Comment: @AleksandarZoric how to use modal on tabBar? can you explain how to use it?

Comment: A lot of examples online on how to do it, this is one example but I am sure there is a simpler one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70189562/react-native-show-a-modal-view-from-a-tabbar-button

Comment: A better one, maybe: https://egghead.io/lessons/react-native-open-a-modal-from-the-tab-bar-in-react-navigation-v5